# Convert time to string with milliseconds

Tags: python

Python datetime.now() gives me current time including milliseconds like this:

```
2014-08-22 19:23:40.630000
```

How do I convert the above datetime object to a string that includes the milliseconds?

I looked into `time.strftime()` but it does not provide an option for milliseconds.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use datetime.strftime. In Python 3.4.1:

```
from datetime import datetime
mytime= datetime.now()
s= mytime.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
print(s)
'2014-Aug-23 08:51:32.911271'
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  Tried time.strftime("%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") on Python 3.4.1 command line and I get  Invalid format string.

Comment: Updated answer for 3.4.1 - works fine for me. Are you using 'time' or 'datetime' ?

Comment: That was problem.  I was using 'time' instead of 'datetime'. Thanks.

Comment: how do I do it with 'time' package, tho?